# performance of validating base64encoded string

Tags: c#

I am working on a application where the user supplies an image to be stored in a database. The data is coming through an xml file but the user is supplying a 1.5MB image in the form of a base64encoded string.

I validate the incoming string using the following code:

```
public static bool IsBase64String(this string s)
{
   s = s.Trim();
   return (s.Length % 4 == 0) && Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$", RegexOptions.None);

}
```

The end user has informed that memory consumption of the application is high so i am investigating cause of the issue.

My gut feeling is this validation of the base64encoded string. I know i could be wrong but could Regex put a burden on memory usage?

Comment: Assuming that valid data is the norm, can you `try` to convert it and `catch` an exception?

Comment: `My gut feeling is this validation of the base64encoded string.` <-- use a memory profiler to confirm this - or at least try it with small images vs large images to confirm your gut